# pass param to service from controller using typeahead in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Looking at this `Plunker` from an answer on `SO`

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/t1neIS?p=preview)

Learning angular and in the controller there is a param `cityName`, I am not sure how that works.

What I am trying to do is that I have a `myController.js` file

```
var app = angular.module("sampleApp");

app.controller('TypeaheadCtrl',['$scope','search', function ($scope, search) {
   $scope.displayed=[];
    search.getResult(searchQuery)
          .then(function (data) {
              $scope.displayed = (data.records);
          });

}]);
```

`myService.js`

```
angular.module('sampleApp').factory('search', ['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http) {
    var sdo = {
        getResult: function (searchQuery) {
            var promise = $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://somewhere.com'
                params: {
                    q: "a"
                }
            });
            promise.success(function (data, status, headers, conf) {
                return data;
            });

            return promise;
        }
    }
    return sdo;
}]);
```

I want to be able to call the service after the third character is typed in the typeahead box and pass the characters to the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `typeahead-min-length="3"` option on `typeahead` input element.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="result" 
  typeahead="suggestion for suggestion in getSuggestion($viewValue)" 
  typeahead-min-length="3"/>
```

Then have function inside controller which will again return a promise.

```
$scope.getSuggestion = function (searchQuery){
    return search.getResult(searchQuery)
      .then(function (data) {
          return data.records;
    });
};
```

Since you have used `.success` the data will get return `getResult` function.
Use `.then` to chain promise so that you can return a data from the success callback.

**Service**

```
angular.module('sampleApp').factory('search', ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http) {
  var sdo = {
    getResult: function(searchQuery) {
      var promise = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://somewhere.com'
        params: {
          q: searchQuery //<-- pass parameter here
        }
      });
      promise.then(function(response) {
        //you could format data here and returned formatted result
        //or you could also do some sort of validation or filtering on data
        return response.data;
      });
      return promise;
    }
  }
  return sdo;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

change your service like this

```
app.factory('search', ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http) {
  var sdo = {};
  sdo.getResult = function(query) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var url = "http://someurlpath/api/" + query;
    $http.get(url)
      .success(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data.data);
      }).error(function(msg, code) {
        deferred.reject(msg);
      });
    return deferred.promise;
  };
  return sdo;
}]);
```